# Running a ShellScript with flags for the command line arguments

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd

The code below which i have developed yesterday , takes either a file(x.txt) or space delimited numbers(434 435 436 437 ) as input and the pushes the data fron either case in an array and loops through.

```
Syntax: shtest.sh 434 435 436 or sh test.sh x.txt

MYFILE=$1 ;
OLDIFS=$IFS;
IFS=' ';

if [ -f "$MYFILE" ]; then
   testCases=($(cat $MYFILE));
else
   testCases=($@);
fi
for testCase in "${testCases[@]}"
do
   echo "Running Testcases $testCase"
done
```

The way i want to do it to make it less error prone

1. I would like to actually have a flag while running the above script with a     file as a paramenter

   sh test.sh -f myFile.txt

   or Can be run with -t flasg with  numbers as the arguments

   sh test.sh -t 434 435 436
2. if Both -f and -t exist, then i have to check and throw an error
   ex:   sh test.sh -f myFile.sh -t 343 435 435 or 
        sh test.sh  -t 343 435 435 -f myFile.sh

I have started working on Shell  Scripting just yesterday, and iam really short of how to do it syntactically

Finally , If we have flagged file or Flagged number arguments (No Unfalgged at all) , would the code  below work or would that have any issues
    Syntax:

```
sh test.sh -f myFile.txt             #should work
sh test.sh -t 443 444 443 443        # should work
sh test.sh -f myFile.txt -t 443 444 443 443  # should fail


 isFile=0;
 isTest=0;

 while getopts ":f:c:t:" opt; do
         case $opt in
         f)
           echo "-f was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
           testCases=($(cat $OPTARG));
           isFile=1;
           ;;
         t)
           # testCases=($@);
            multi+=("$OPTARG")
            for val in "${multi[@]}"; do
                   echo " - $val"
            done
            ;;
         c)
           echo "-c was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2;
           isTest=1;
           ;;
         \?)
           echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
           exit 1
           ;;
         :)
           echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
           exit 1
           ;;
       esac
     done

 # Exit if both flags are sent
 if [ isTest==1 && isFile==1 ]; then
 {
   echo "Exiting";
 }
 fi

 #if the flag is not avaiable, the store the orphan numbers (Command Line Arguments)


 for testCase in "${testCases[@]}"
 do
    echo "Running Testcases $testCase"
 done
```

Please advice and any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Tejas

Answer (score 0):

After the `while getopts` loop, add:

```
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

if [ $isFile = 0 ] && [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "$0: must specify file (-f file) or numbers" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I assume that you have `isFile=0` before your loop.  If you don't set it explicitly, you could inherit an environment variable that the user set accidentally.  Always be careful that you don't accidentally use environment variables from the code that invokes your script.

Comment: what does shift $(($OPTIND - 1)) , and what if have flags for both numbers and files...
Posted a new code for this scenario.please check and advice

Comment: The `shift` removes the options that have been 'used' by `getopts` from `"$@"` (the list of positional parameters) leaving just the non-option arguments.  The code shown already accepts both a file and some numbers; it only demands either a file or some numbers but doesn't diagnose both a file and some numbers.  Adjust the tests to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes , now the requirement is having flags for both numbers and file . I will try looking at ur code and will change mine acccordingly, thanks